# IE input background image issue

Tags: internet-explorer, input, background

IE the only browser that needs aditional mantainance(someone should pay for this)
Here's my problem: I have created some inputs with a background image they work with FF, Chorme, IE9 (did not tested Opera, Safari) but not with IE7 and IE8 where the text is overflowing the image by ignoring the padding or scroll the image(IE7)..

The code:
http://jsfiddle.net/CEjXe/12/

I know i can wrap the input with a div and style the div with padding and background image. I’m looking for a different solution css/js only (if there is 1).

Thanks

PS: reducing max-lenght is not an option as many users have long e-mail adresses or passwords, plus i'm using inputs for more fields.

Comment: I have found similar issue in IE7. Here is a workaround for that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728717/how-to-prevent-background-image-from-scrolling-in-form-field-in-ie

Comment: Hi, as i said above it's a known solution :) was looking for something else witch dosent require html changes. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution ?, how did you did it ? I had to hide the image for I.E !

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607198/padding-a-text-input-in-ie-possible